# Child component updates parent then parent updates another child component's Input value

Tags: javascript, angular, parent-child, onchange

I know this question might have been asked dozens of times here, but I've reached all the approaches and I still can get it to work (I've tried with a subscription on the child and ngOnchanges)

So this is the basic structure of my project's issue:
[image]

**Template on parent**

```
<child-a (updateParentOnSave)="updateOnSave($event)"></child-a>
<child-b [myObjectData]="myObjectData"></child-b>
```

**On Child A:**

After calling a certain method I emit this value to the **parent** component

```
this.updateParentOnSave.emit({ someFlag: false, myData: this.myData });
```

**On Parent**

```
 updateOnSave(updateData: any): void {
      this.someFlag = updateData.someFlag;
      // Update the child data
      this.myObjectData = {...updateData.myData}; // Using spread operator since the received data is an object.
    }
  }
```

Up to this point, everything works, fine I can see the value of `updateData.myData` on the parent where `this.myObjectData` is the `@Input` value on Child B

**On Child B**

Here I have a certain non-relevant method, that once it is called should used the value of `this.myObjectData` And this is what I have so far:

```
myData: any;
@Input() myObjectData: any;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (this.myObjectData) { // Added this to avoid the initial undefined
      this.myData= changes.myObjectData.currentValue;
    }
  }

  // This method is only called after the @Input myObjectData was updated on the parent
  someInvokedFunction(): void {
    console.log(this.myData); // THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED ALWAYS
  }
```

So I've tried everything, even using a getter/setter and it never works I keep getting undefind when `someInvokedFunction` gets called.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here,

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (this.myObjectData) { // Added this to avoid the initial undefined
      this.myData= changes.myObjectData.currentValue;
    }
  }
```

I think you probably meant to put `changes.myObjectData`.

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.myObjectData) { // Added this to avoid the initial undefined
      this.myData= changes.myObjectData.currentValue;
    }
  }
```

[Here](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) is the documentation regarding that hook in case you're curious when and why it fires.

Comment: I'm accepting your question since you were right in that section, but my true error was adding the input in the wrong component (facepalm) 
Thanks for your answer!